# can i append integer value to stringbuilder?

Tags: java, rest, url, spring-mvc, stringbuffer

I written a controller is following

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{roleId}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
 public String updateRole(@PathVariable Integer roleId,@Valid UserRoleResource roleDTO,  
 ModelMap  modelMap) {
    UserRole userRoleforduplicate = userRoleService.findByRoleName(roleDTO.getRoleName());

    if(userRoleforduplicate==null)
    {
        UserRole userRole =   
    mapper.updateUserRoleFrom(roleDTO,userRoleService.findById(roleId));    
        userRoleService.update(userRole);
        modelMap.addAttribute("user_role", userRole);
        modelMap.addAttribute("roleId", userRole.getRoleId());
        this.succes="redirect:/roles/listroles";
    }
    else
    {
        Object s="Role Name Already Exist";
        modelMap.addAttribute("aslam", s);
        this.succes="redirect:/roles/updateLoadDetails/roleId";     
        }
    return succes;
}
```

In which the else part is not working properly because the variable succes is a string and the roleId is a Integer,So it throws the following error

```
 Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested  
 exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "roleId"
```

For this issue can i append the roleId to StringBuilder ?Like

```
 String s1="redirect:/roles/updateLoadDetails/";
 Integer i2=roleId;
 stringbuilder.append(s1); 
 stringbuilder.append(i2);
 return stringbuilder;
```

Or any other option to pass a integer value to string?? plz anybody help

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of below code

```
String s1="redirect:/roles/updateLoadDetails/";
 Integer i2=roleId;
 stringbuilder.append(s1); 
 stringbuilder.append(i2);
```

you can also use this one so that lines of code will less

```
stringbuilder.append("redirect:/roles/updateLoadDetails/").appnd(""+roleId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) like this:

```
String s = String.format("redirect:/roles/updateLoadDetails/%d", roleId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
stringbuilder.append(i2);
```

With

```
stringbuilder.append(""+i2);
```

Comment: Or even combine your two stringbuilder lines to : stringbuilder.append(s1+i2);